# Apex Trigger - Write a trigger on contact to prevent duplicate records based on Contact Email & Contact Phone

Tags: apex, trigger, contact

I am trying to make trigger with best practice i.e. by creating Handler class. I am not getting what should be done in this scenario. I have written some code as per my understanding. Kindly check and help me out with a bit of explanation.

```java
public with sharing class contactTriggerHandler {
    public static void onBeforeInsert(List<Contact> contactList){
        checkEmailPhone();
    }

    public static void onBeforeUpdate(List<Contact> contactList){
        checkEmailPhone();
    }

    public static void checkEmailPhone(List<Contact> conList, Map<Id,Contact> conMap){
        Map<Id, Contact> dupEmailPhoneMap = new Map<Id, Contact>();
        List<Contact> dupEmailPhoneList = new List<Contact>();
        dupEmailPhoneList = [SELECT Id, Email, Phone FROM Contact WHERE Id IN : conMap]
        for(contact con : dupEmailPhoneList]{
            if(conMap.values().Email.contains(con.Email) || (conMap.values().Phone.contains(con.Phone)){
                 con.addError('Duplicate Phone number or Email address');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe best practice here would be to use Duplicate Rules instead of a trigger here.

Comment: I think Duplicate Rule will not work when I will undelete any record from recycle bin. That is why I thought of trigger. And i am new to Salesforce. This is for my practice.

Comment: N.B. Duplicate Rules don't apply intrabatch - that is, if a trigger receives 2 identical recs in one transaction, they won't be detected as dups on DML. Your trigger handler also doesn't accommodate this use case. You should note that your class won't compile and that needs to be addressed too.

Answer (score -1):

Try this out. Directly implemented the logic in Trigger, You can move it to Handler once this works for you.

```
Trigger preventContactDuplicate on Contact(Before Insert, Before Update) { 
    
    Map<String, Contact> existingContacts = new Map<String, Contact>();
    Set<String> emailSet = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> phoneSet = new Set<String>();
    
    for(Contact cnt: Trigger.New) {   
        emailSet.add(cnt.Email);
        phoneSet.add(cnt.Phone);
    }
    
    for(Contact ct: [SELECT Id, Email, Phone FROM Contact where Email IN:emailSet and  Phone IN: phoneSet]) {
        existingContacts.put(ct.Email + '-'+ ct.Phone, ct);
    }
    for(Contact cnt: Trigger.New) {   
        If(existingContacts.get(cnt.Email + '-'+ cnt.Phone) != null ) {                
            if( Trigger.isInsert || (Trigger.IsUpdate && cnt.Id != existingContacts.get(cnt.Email + '-'+ cnt.Phone).Id)) {                   
                cnt.addError('Duplicate Contact');
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This trigger risks impacting multiple governor limits, including query rows, CPU time, and heap size. This shouldn't be done in a trigger.